# Trigger code when custom event is being bound in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, custom-events

JQuery has great support for custom events - `.bind("foo", function(e)...`. However what if the mechanic of triggering the event is not ready yet and has to be constructed only on those elements that have the event bound on?

For example I want a `scrollin` event that gets fired when an element is scrolled into a viewport. To do this, I would `onscroll` have to check all the elements and `trigger` `scrollin` on those that were outside the viewport and now are inside. This is not acceptable.

There are some tricks to speed it up. For example one of the plugins for this checks all the elements in "private" `$.cache` and does the checking only on those that have `scrollin` event bound.

But that's also ugly. What I need is an additional callback for the *binding* of the event (additional to the callback for handling) that would take care of the scroll management, that is to put the element(s) into some `elementsCheckOnScrol` cache array.

I'm looking for something like:

```
$.delegateBind("scrollin", function(jqSelection) { ... });
element.bind("scrollin", function(e) {..}); //Calls ^ after internal bind management
```

Edit: This would be nice api!

```
$.bind("bind", function(onWhat) { ... })
```

:-)

Comment: event delegation, and the .live method might grant you what you wish. And a little demo could help us help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an `$.event.special` API, but I don't know "how much" public it is. It is not in the docs and has been changed at least once before. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding you, you could patch the `bind` method like this:

```
(function($) {
    var oldBind = $.fn.bind;

    $.fn.bind = function(name) { 
        if(name === "scrollin") {
             delegateFunction(this);
        }

        oldBind.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

What it does is checking whether a `scrollin` is being bound, and if so, calls your delegate function. After that it simply calls the original bind function which does all jQuery things like it does regularly.

After having added this code, you could use it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/g4k2G/.

```
function delegateFunction(selection) {
    alert(selection.length);
}

$('a').bind('scrollin', function() {});
```

Note that this does not support object literals being passed to `.bind` (only `(name, func)`), but you could implement that as well.

Comment: Thanks, that would work but i was hoping for some more clean solution :-)

Comment: @tillda: I'm not sure if what you want is built in natively.